# Left to right mark added to field name

Tags: 7, debugging

Using Drupal's admin I added to an existing content type a new text field with the machine name `field_note`.

When fetching the field in my code I want to check if `$field_name == 'field_note'` but it never does. When printing the value of `$field_name` I get `field_note` (should match).

Anyway, after a long process and looking at the hex values of both strings I found out that `$field_name` has 3 additional control characters at its end - the LRM (left to right mark).  My workaround for this was using the following code:

```
$field_name=preg_replace('/\p{C}+/u', "", $field_name);
```

This works well, but I really want to understand why this happened? I have dozens of fields and only now this started happening with new fields.

A really big clue might be a recent upgrade from Drupal 7.23 to 7.63, but checking the database and field table they all remained with the same encoding.